# Bind value to the link url

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue-router.

How do I bind value to a link?

```
<a v-link="'people/edit/{{ item.id }}'">Edit</a>
```

Error:

```
link="'people/edit/{{ item.id}}'": attribute interpolation is not allowed in Vue.js directives and special attributes.
```

Comment: How about `v-link="'people/edit/' + item.id"`?

Comment: @Dogbert it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `+` to concatenate the strings here since `v-link` accepts JavaScript expressions:

```
<a v-link="'people/edit/' + item.id">Edit</a>
```

> `v-link` is the directive for enabling user navigation in a router-enabled app. It accepts a JavaScript expression which will be passed to `router.go()` internally.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/link.md

Answer (score 3):

You can't use mustaches into the v-link, v-link is basically vanilla js, and mustaches as templating part are not allowed.

If you are using ES2015, you can go with template strings.

```
<a v-link="`/people/edit/${item.id}`">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

vlink attribute specifies the color of visited links in a document, it's not used as you have used it. To create link href is used at place of vlink. Eg below

```
<a href="people/edit/${item.id}"></a>
```

Comment: Since I us vue-router, the link is not http://localhost:8080/#!/people/edit/3871287183